# Retrieving the data datewise in hive in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I am making an app using flutter and creating a **database using hive**, the user will get an option to save the transaction detail based on some fields [image: shown below]
Now what I want is that based on **the date of the transaction the sum of all the transactions on a particular month and then showing its sum** on a specific page like this [image: example image]

The code by which I am creating the form fields

```
class Transaction extends HiveObject {
 @HiveField(0)
 String paymentMode;
 @HiveField(1)
 bool unnecessary;
 @HiveField(2)
 String title;
 @HiveField(3)
 DateTime createdOn;
 @HiveField(4)
 int amount;
 @HiveField(5)
 String category;

 Transaction({
  this.paymentMode = "",
  this.unnecessary = false,
  this.title = "",
  this.createdOn,
  this.amount = 0,
  this.category="",
  });

  Transaction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>  map) :
    paymentMode = map['paymentMode']  ?? "",
    unnecessary = map['unnecessary']  ?? false,
    title = map['title']  ?? "",
    createdOn = map['createdOn']  ?? DateTime.now(),
    amount = map['amount']  ?? 0,
    category = map['category'] ?? "";

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'paymentMode': paymentMode,
    'unnecessary': false,
    'title': title,
    'createdOn': createdOn,
    'amount': amount,
    'category': category,
     };

  Transaction copyWith({
    String paymentMode,
    bool unnecessary,
    String title,
    DateTime createdOn,
    User user,
    int amount,
    String category,
    }) {
    return Transaction(
     paymentMode: paymentMode ?? this.paymentMode,
     unnecessary: unnecessary ?? this.unnecessary,
     title: title ?? this.title,
     createdOn: createdOn ?? this.createdOn,
     amount: amount ?? this.amount,
     category: category ?? this.category,
       );
   }
```

The code

Answer (score 0):

I am supposing you have a list of `Transaction` objects,
You can simply sort that list using sort function.

```
listOftransactions.sort((a,b)=>a.createdOn.compareTo(b.createdOn));
```

This will sort the list according to timestamp, and if you want to reverse the order just replace  `a` with `b` in the inline function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I wanted the sum of "amount" for all the transactions saved by the user in a month like for example in the first image there are transactions t1 and t2(both are of January) what I want is to display the sum of both transactions in the 2nd image January field, please help me with itAgain thanks for your answer

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: Run a for loop and increment the amount, simple